# Endeca Thesaurus not working as expected

Tags: endeca

We have put two entry in thesaurus non-stick and non stick as a multi-way.

As per thesaurus endeca document when you put entry as a multi-way then any of the search term you search it will give you a results of all.

So here our assumption is if I search non-stick or non stick the results count should be same.

But it give us different results set and for non-stick term it giving less results.

After some analysis we observe when we search for non stick term it searches for non-stick, non stick, and stick non. While for non-stick it search only for non-stick and non stick but it is not searching stick non.

How can we resolve this issue?

Comment: Try adding `non stick` as a phrase in the `Automatic Phrasing` section in Experience Manager.

Comment: what is match mod for search?is it any?

Comment: Match Mode is AllPartial

Comment: Can you try with match mod - All?

Comment: Yes, I have tried in endeca_jspref but not any luck

Answer (score 0):

By default endeca does not index 'special characters'  (i.e. charachters that are not alpha numeric), It also does not trigger thesaurus entries for special characters. So if you create such an entry non-stick will not trigger the entry, but non stick will.

You can read more about this in the endeca documentation which give a complex example using ice cream, ice-cream, 'ice cream' etc.